# nuget restore not finding version of package even though in-range version available

Tags: package, nuget, version, restore

```
Visual Studio 2019
.NET Core 2.2.0
```

When run `Visual Studio > Solution Explorer > Restore NuGet Packages` or command-line `nuget restore` outputs many errors that required package version can't be found.

Here's an example :

```
Unable to find package System.Runtime.Extensions with version (>= 4.3.0)
  - Found 2 version(s) in MyFeed [ Nearest version: 4.3.1 ]
```

Our dev environment is restricted environment with no internet access.

`MyFeed` is a network folder where we store all packages versions required as dependencies by our projects.

Here's the relevant contents :

```
/system.runtime.extensions
  /4.0.10
  /4.3.1
```

The package version constraint is `System.Runtime.Extensions >= 4.3.0`
so why wouldn't `nuget restore` recognize `4.3.1` as a qualified package version ?

Is there a `NuGet.config` setting I'm not aware of that disables matching within a dependency's version range ?

Comment: Can you show us the PackageReference, please?